Question about the orbits
in Quran 21:33 and Quran 36:40 are the sun and moons orbits meant from our perspective? (with the rising and setting of them) bc the orbits of the day and night seem to mean from our perspectives so wouldnt the same apply for the sun and moon?
i know the sun has its own orbit, but in these verses the way the day and night and sun and moons orbits are mentioned seems relative to each other and it wouldnt make sense that the suns orbit affects the day and night
The word being used, falak, فلك, is it referring strictly to a circular motion of the sun and moons orbits? Or can it refer to the way we see the sun and moon rising and setting in a curved way?

I see you already understand the concept of perspective: viewed from earth, the sun is orbiting earth, but the mathematical equations to describe the motion are far less complex if we think of the earth orbiting the sun. Alas, I'm no expert on Islamic interpretation of the Quran.

@GyroGearloose But if these verses are meant to focus on perspective, then its likely meant to highlight how perfect God's creation is with the moon and sun rising and set regularly, creating day and night, which shows the divine design and harmony in Allah's creation. I think its supposed to be explained like other verses in a simple manner that anyone can understand, so I don't know why you mentioned mathematical equations describing motion. Unless I misunderstood your comment, and if so my apologies.
